# Gunicorn - ModuleNotFound crispy_forms (But is installed)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to setup Crispy Forms on my Django environment. I have installed Crispy Forms using `pip3 install --user django_crispy_forms` and I have added the `'crispy_forms'` to the INSTALLED APPS within my settings.py file.

Although, I am unable to boot up my gunicorn service file, as an error is displaying `"ModuleNotFound Error crispy_forms"`

Just to ensure that Crispy Forms is installed, I tried to rerun the installation to which I receive a message "requirements are already satisfied".

Any ideas to what could be causing this behaviour?

Edit: If I remove `'crispy_forms'` from the INSTALLED APPS area, my gunicorn service boots up perfectly fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install it inside your env?

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your response! I tried installing it both ways, at root level and from within my Django environment to no avail. I have done a little research online and I know quite a few people have ran in to similar issues recently. One user on Stack Overflow, has advised to install via easy_install. But I can't figure out how to install the SetupTools for Pip. I already have Python3 and Pip3 installed but I don't currently have access to the easy_install command on my CentOS server.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue!

Here's what I did - Using the newest version of Crispy Forms didn't seem to work and my Gunicorn was throwing the "ModuleNotFound" error during the boot up phase.

So I instead installed `django-crispy-forms==1.9.2` by making it apart of my requirements list and then running `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` which resolved my issue.